# Values not generating for last month in datetime php

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get the number of sat&sun for each month between two given dates.

eg: For start_date as 5-Jul-2015 and end_date as 29-Aug-2015 I need to get 7 sat&sun in Jul and 9 in Aug.

So far I am getting values till the second last month ie: not getting Aug. 
What to do?

### Code

```
$countSat = 0;
$countSun = 0;
$start = new DateTime('05-07-2015');
$month = $start->format('n');
$end = new DateTime('29-08-2015');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$i = 0;
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    if ($month != $dt->format('n')) {
        $results[$i] = $countSun + $countSat;
        $i++;
        $countSun = 0;
        $countSat = 0;
    }

    if ($dt->format('N') == 7) {
        $countSun++;
    }
    if ($dt->format('N') == 6) {
        $countSat++;
    }
    $month = $dt->format('n');
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to add the results after the loop is done. The month will only change from 7 to 8 inside the loop.
Thus the days of the last month are being counted but never added.

```
$countSat = 0;
$countSun = 0;
$start = new DateTime('05-07-2015');
$month = $start->format('n');
$end = new DateTime('29-08-2015');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$i = 0;
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    if ($month != $dt->format('n')) {
        $results[$i] = $countSun + $countSat;
        $i++;
        $countSun = 0;
        $countSat = 0;
    }

    if ($dt->format('N') == 7) {
        $countSun++;
    }
    if ($dt->format('N') == 6) {
        $countSat++;
    }
    $month = $dt->format('n');
}

$results[$i] = $countSun + $countSat;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
```